# How to make my web server sends data on behalf of the client to another domain?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

At office, we have an asp web server with high internet speed (let's call it server A). The clients internet speed are limited by our network administrator. The main web server(let's call it server B) lies on a remote location.

I want server A to act as an agent for the client pc's. i.e sends requests to server B on behalf of the clients.

For instance, at the clients side the code will be similar to this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form action="http://server-a.com" method="post" target="theIframe">
        <input name="data" value="{client data to be sent here}" />
    </form>
    <iframe name="theIframe" style="display:none"></iframe>
    <script>
        document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

That's it, server A will receive the clients data as parameters then send them to server B.

What exactly should I do at server A?

Should I make it as a web service, web Api, class library?

I'm confused.. as server A will contain functions that receive parameters from clients and send http requests on behalf..

I appreciate your recommendations.

Comment: You're describing a "proxy." Rather than rolling your own, why not just use an existing proxy server like Squid?

Comment: @EricLaw Is it a proxy? well our own server lies in the same LAN network. Never heard of Squid

Comment: Certainly sounds like a proxy.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2010/04/02/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr.aspx